# Data scattered in CSV after removing columns using R

Tags: r, csv, arabic, tweets

So, I am using the following code in R to remove certain columns in CSV files located in subdirectories. Each CSV file contains thousands of Arabic tweets. However, the output is not exactly what I expect. Values move between cells as shown in the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkzMy.png): Red frame is the output, Green frame is the **desired** output. As shown, I expect the data to be in four columns. Instead, they get scattered in many column. Help is appreciated.

Edit: links to file samples:

Original file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/109oU8YmAg5BTkyP5eLlpIeY9eO8z24u0/view

Output file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IhZ_Fom9OingtGmNKY0mqJ80dpuJJDxy/view

```
library("data.table")
library("purrr")
setwd("F:\\2011")
dat.files  <- list.files(path="F:\\2011",
                          recursive=T,
                          pattern="\\.csv$"
                          ,full.names=T)
dir.create("cleaned_2011")
walk(dat.files, function(x) {
DT <- fread(x, sep=",")
DT[, c("id","conversation_id","created_at","date","timezone","user_id","username","place","mentions","urls","photos","replies_count","retweets_count","likes_count","hashtags","cashtags","link","retweet","quote_url","video","thumbnail","near","geo","source","user_rt_id","user_rt","retweet_id","reply_to","retweet_date","translate","trans_src","trans_dest") := NULL]
fwrite(DT, file.path("cleaned_2011", basename(x)), sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide couple of csvs using which we can reproduce the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Sure @RonakShah  I added samples for the original and output files in the main post.

Comment: I think your data has text with comma in it, hence it is splitting the columns. Have you tried changing the separator to something else?

Comment: I have not, because I will have to change the separator in hundreds of files to do that.

Comment: All my files are comma separated values